# Assume that $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$. Prove that there are linear maps $T:V\to W$ and $S:W\to V$ such as T is injective and S is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces, and assume that $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$. Prove that there are linear maps $T:V\to W$ and $S:W\to V$ such as T is injective and S is surjective.

I've been breaking my head to solve this, using the rank-nullity theorem, but to no fruit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two basis $\mathcal{B}_{V} = \{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{m}\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{W} = \{w_{1},w_{2},\ldots,w_{n}\}$, where $0 < m < n$.

Then you can construct the linear mapping $T:V\to W$ as $T(v_{i}) = w_{i}$, for $1\leq i \leq m$.

Indeed, $T$ is injective, as the following reasoning allows us to conclude:
\begin{align*}
T(v) = 0 & \Rightarrow T(a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + a_{m}v_{m}) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow a_{1}T(v_{1}) + a_{2}T(v_{2}) + \ldots + a_{m}T(v_{m}) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow a_{1}w_{1} + a_{2}w_{2} + \ldots + a_{m}w_{m} = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow a_{1} = a_{2} = \ldots = a_{m} = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow v= 0 
\end{align*}

That is because $\ker(T) = \{0\}$, and we are done.

In order to build $S$, you can make a similar approach as done before.

Let $S(w_{i}) = v_{i}$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ and let $T(w_{i}) = v_{1}$ for $m + 1\leq i \leq n$. Then one has that:
\begin{align*}
v\in V \Rightarrow v & = a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + a_{m}v_{m}\\\\
& = a_{1}S(w_{1}) + a_{2}S(w_{2}) + \ldots + a_{m}S(w_{m})\\\\
& = a_{1}S(w_{1}) + a_{2}S(w_{2}) + \ldots + a_{m}S(w_{m}) + 0S(w_{m+1}) + \ldots + 0S(w_{n})
\end{align*}

But what does this result represent? Since $\text{Im}(S) = \text{span}(S(\mathcal{B}_{W}))$, we have just proven that $V\subseteq\text{Im}(S)$. Once the inclusion $\text{Im}(S)\subseteq V$ does always hold, we have just deduced that $S$ is surjective.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But would it be possible and simple to solve this problem using the nullity-rank theorem? I was trying this and my mind simply couldn't find a way out using the theorem.

Comment: Also, if I understood correctly, $Im(S) = span(S(Bw))$ is equivalent to $Im(S) = span(Bv)$?

Comment: For any function $f:X\to Y$, one always has that $f(X)\subseteq Y$. If the equality $f(X) = Y$ holds, then we say that $f$ is surjective.